# How to change trail renderer start width dynamically by script in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript

I created a prefab that contains a trail renderer to draw a sprite in the GUI which I in a GameObject in a script.

I want to change the start width or end width of the trail renderer dynamically during run time. Could anyone help me how write code to access to the trail renderer prefab to change that property?

Comment: What have you tried with the code? What do you have so far? What's not working about it?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Unity, so I will make a few assumptions:

1. You tried to make a TrailRenderer, but don't know "how to change trail renderer start width dynamically by script in unity?".
2. So far, you have a TrailRenderer, but don't know "how to change trail renderer start width dynamically by script in unity?".
3. The TrailRenderer that you have so far is working, but you don't know "how to change trail renderer start width dynamically by script in unity?".

I had to Google "Trail Renderer Unity" to see if that was a Unity thing or a class you'd created. Here are the first two links that Google returns:

Link to the manual page: [manual reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html)
Link to the scripting page: [script reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TrailRenderer.html)

`endWidth` and `startWidth` are listed right after the first entry on the script reference page and should allow you to achieve what you want.